# send an SMS and have a confirmation of sending with the native sms application

Tags: android

I use in my application, the application sms of android and I would like to have a return when the message is sent:

[sms activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e50kC.png)

[Onresult methode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9B06.png)

my code :

ActivityResult return nothink , i dont understand. I just want to know when button send is pressed or when message is send .  :)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Simply add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMS intent does not return result, You have to use sms broadcast receiver for this, following is the required permission and broadcast receiver for this..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>



<receiver android:name=".SmsIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: ok thank you for your answer , did you have site or exemple for implement this broadcasr receiver ?                                                                                                i found this : http://www.tutos-android.com/broadcast-receiver-android